# DB design question

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database-design, data-structures

**Requirement:** Manager will assign targets to his subordinates and subordinates will report on these targets.

**Requirements Elaborated:** Manager will create a **project** and give its **start date** and **end date**. Manager will add **subordinates** in project and also add **activities** in project from list of activities. Manager will **assign targets** to his subordinates and select **frequency** of report. Frequency can be **Yearly, Monthly, Quarterly, Weekly**. Subordinates will report on these assigned targets.

**Manager assign targets like**:

- **Start Date:** 1 jan 2011 *(Start date of project)*
- **End Date**: 31 Dec 2011  *(End date of project)*
- **Frequency:** Monthly   *(Frequency of report, other values are
  yearly, quartely, weekly)*

**Activities:**

- Install OS on machines
- Install SQL Server on server machines

**Assigned Targets:**

- Install OS on machines: 100
- Install SQL Server on server machines: 10

**Locations:**

- London
- New York
- Paris

Now there would be **12 reports** (one for each month) and subordinates on these locations have to report monthly. Assigned targets are for each month.

I am little confused about the design of all this.

**Q1-** Should I generate reports for each months and location in advance and save in db? When user will login to system to report he will see 12 reports (because frequency is monthly, if frequency is weekly then 52 reports) and open a report to report his activities.

**Q2-** Should I just save Assigned targets in one table, Locations in another table, report frequency in third table and when subordinate report on assigned target for specific month and for specific location then save this data to some other table and link this data.

**Q3-** Any other idea of doing this?

**Q4-** Manager can also change report frequency. How should I handle this becasue if subordinates has reported on targets then how to change all this?

Thanks.

**Note:**
If this question is not suitable for Stackoverflow then please move this (or tell me) to suitable stackexchange site.

Comment: Q1 Report should be done after the task done. You should not create report in advance, especially because Manager can change the report frequency (Q4)

Comment: Thanks @Rudy, Good point waiting others to comment on this.

Comment: Question : for "Install OS on machines: 100" what does the 100 mean?

Comment: This is just dummy data. But here (for example) 100  windows on 100 diff machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1: I would store “frequency of reports” as an attribute of Target. Reports would be logged in the database if, when, and as they are generated by the subordinates. Ensuring/enforcing their delivery is outside the scope of a mere database structure.

Q2: What is Location an attribute of: Project, ProjectAttribute, Target, or other? Store it there. You’d probably have a separate table for Locations as well, particularly if there are Location-specific attributes.

Q3: Some questions: Is there a relation between Attributes and Targets? Is there one Manager, or several? If only ever one, then I don’t think you need to model him/her; if several, you then have to determine and structure the relationship between Managers and Subordinates. (Can a Manager be another Manager’s subordinate?) Subordinates are assigned to Projects by Managers, and assigned Targets in those Projects by Managers. Can a Subordinate be assigned (associated) with a Project without having any currently assigned Targets? How about the reverse?

Q4: As per Q1, log reports as they are submitted, and let the Manager chew the subordinate out if they’re not hitting the desired schedule. Question: If the Manager changes the report frequency, do you need to track what the frequency was at any give point in time? (Probably not, but you never know.)

Comment: **Ensuring/enforcing their delivery is outside the scope of a mere database structure.** What do you mean by this? Can you please explain a little more.   **Is there one Manager, or several?** Yes, only one.  **Can a Manager be another Manager’s subordinate?** NO  **Can a Subordinate be assigned (associated) with a Project without having any currently assigned Targets?** Yes, sometimes manager add subordinates in project but don't assign them targets. But if targets are not assigned that subordinate will not see this project in his list so I think no issue?

Comment: **Is there a relation between Attributes and Targets?** If by attributes you mean Location and Subordinates then yes, there is relation b/w location and target. E.g. One subordinate (Philip) can have diff targets on diff location.

Comment: Regarding "enforcing reports": If a report is to be delivered monthly, at what point in time must the report be added to the database? What if the subordinate enters it early, or late, or never? **Must** there be an entry in the database for that report, even if the entry only says "subordinate has not entered the report yet"? These are all essentially "data chaning ove time" issues (i.e. when does data entry occur), and not database structure/architecture issues. So yes, provide space for the report within the database, but strictly speaking, the report creation event is not a database issue.

Comment: By the by, my answer is more in the form of raising and discussing issues and topics. Database design rarely has black-and-white right-or-wrong answers.

Comment: @Phill, it is so kind of you that you spare your time for me and share your thoughts. I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kashif, you need to have **below tables:**

1- **Projects**   --- columns: (start date, end date, Report frequency) etc

2- **ProjectDetails** columns: (ProjectId, LocationId) etc

3- **Locations**

4- **SubOrdinates**

5- **Activities**

5- **Tasks** --- columns: (ProjectDetailId, SubordinateId, ActivityId) etc

6- **Reports** -- columns: (ProjectDetailId, SubordinateId,  ReportDate, Year, Month, Week, ReportData)

The Reports table will have no data until a subordinate reports to the Manager. When he reports an entry will be made in this table.

You can generate the report list for the users when they login to the system, based on the Projects.ReportFrequency. You will need an intelligent logic here.